# SQL Server 2014 Express Setup is not creating Configuration.ini file

Tags: installation, sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to create a "Configuration.ini" file to automate a future SQL Server Express 2014 installation. I have found several posts from all over the 'Net that tell me to go thru the installation as normal, choose all my settings, and before it's ready to install, the "Ready to Install" text on the left-hand corner of the screen will be bold and there will be a TextBox on the bottom with a path to the configuration file. As it turns out, neither one of these are showing up on the screen, and the Setup is not creating a Configuration.ini file. Why is it not creating an .ini file for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a post on codeproject.com that answered my question (http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/713204/SQL-Server-How-to-generate-a-configuration-fi)  . When launching the setup.exe file for SQL Server 2014 Express, you need to pass in the following parameters when running the setup.exe in order for it to create a configuration.ini file:

***Setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /UIMODE=Normal***

When you pass in these parameters to the setup, not only will it create a Configuration.ini file for you, but you will be presented with a more detailed installation wizard with more options, including an option to either specify a "free" edition, or enter a product key.

Here is a screenshot of the what the wizard will look like when it show a link to the configuration.ini file

[image]

Comment: please be notice,first create bat file copy cmd command and run bat file